# Sharing detail with email for windows mobile7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am working on an application for windows mobile 7.
I need to send some information from my application to some user via email.
I am using "EmailComposeTask()" for this. But i am getting error "email cant send. make sure u have setup an accout"

How to setup an email account in windows7 emulator.
Can anyone help me?

Following code i am using ...

`emailComposeTask = new EmailComposeTask();
            emailComposeTask.Body = textBox1.Text;
            emailComposeTask.To = textBox2.Text;
            emailComposeTask.From=TextBox3.Text;
            emailComposeTask.Show();`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EmailComposeTask can't be used in the emulator.

Your code seems correct, it should work on a real device.